# How can I get the name of a windows .bat script from within the script itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, nant

I have a .bat file. I want to programmatically get the name of the .bat file. How can I do this?

*This is my end goal*

```
"..\lib\nant\nant.exe" -buildfile:nant.build {{pass in name of this file here}}
pause
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `for /?` on the command line. The help shows all kinds of useful filename substitutions, such as:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
```

Replace I with 0 to get just the batch file name, and replace I with 1, 2, 3, etc. to get argument names.

Comment: I ended up with the following:

"..\lib\nant\nant.exe" -buildfile:nant.build %~n0
pause

Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The %0% variable will give you the fully qualified path to the batch file, including its name. There may be a better way to get just the name.

Comment: It's just `%0` as it's no variable but an argument.